# What is this tag called? <?xml ?>

Tags: xml, svg

I have worked with a variety of XML-based documents, and they often being with a line similar to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I understand that this line dictates the version and encoding of the proceeding document.

I'm currently writing up a report on SVG, and I need to refer to the tag in the document, however I do not know it's name.

What is the name of the tag?

***EDIT:* This is not a duplicate question:**

I have seen discussions of a similar nature on other questions, however I have not seen anyone directly reference the name of the tag.

Comment: @Quentin please tell me where in that answer they refer to the name of tag?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/imhK6ZS.png (and it isn't a tag)

Comment: And it is called the `XML prolog`.

Comment: Thank you @PeterB

Comment: @PeterB, which is it? XML prolog or XML declaration?